# Stopping the User From Accessing The Application When Using the Back Button

Tags: c#, xaml, security, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am making a simple password managing application, which requires the user to remember one 'Master Password' to access all his/her other passwords stored on the application.

However my problem is the back button (and multitasking). As if the user (or more importantly, other person) uses these, he/she can access the app without having to go past the initial verification page.

Is there any way to deter this problem?

Or is there a way to simply kill the application when the start button is pressed? (to achieve the same effect as when you exit an app using the back button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application targets Windows Phone 7 (which will run on Phone 8) you can exit an app with the following line:

```
new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game().Exit();
```

This is found in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game assembly.

Comment: As I am making the app for both 7.1-.8 and 8 is there anything that works for both operA

Comment: As I am masking my app for both 7 and 8 is there anything that works for both operating systems?

Comment: Do you have two separate projects? One targeting Phone 7 and one targeting Phone 8? If you only have a Phone 7 application (which works on Phone 8) then you will be ok. The same API will work.

Comment: Yeah I'm making it for windows phone 7.1 but targeting it at both 7&8

Comment: Then the above code will work for you. I placed it in the Application_Deactived event of the App.xaml.cs

Comment: I get the error "`The type or namespace name 'Xna' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`" and see no obvious `using` statement to add. What can I do?

Comment: Add a reference to the  Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game assembly

Comment: Have done that, thanks. However I get the following error: `InvalidOperationException was unhandled` `Navigation is not allowed when the task is not in the foreground. Error: -2147220990` As I need to put it under the `Deactivated` event in App.xaml.cs so the application is truly killed when the user exits.

Comment: I did not test this on a device, only emulator. You could also place the code in the Application_Activated event, or set a bool in that event and in Page code exit the app...

Comment: I tried in activated, that seems to give a really bad user experience ufortunatly, how would I go about making this bool event you mentioned

Comment: The experience would be similar to the activated, so if you don't like that approach no need to go down the other path.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for all the help, I ended up using a messageboxresult under activated in app.xaml which goes back to the start page.

Comment: Do you just want the user to login again every time they open/activate the app?

Comment: Yeah exactly, do you know how to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Application_Activated event in App.xaml.cs to detect this and apply your logic accordingly e.g. ask again for authentication.
There is no API to close application for Windows Phone 7. For Windows Phone 8 you can use Application.Current.Terminate();

Comment: When I try to add a Navigation handler to Application_Activated it won't let me? Is there any other work-around for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the best solution for you. 
In app.xaml.cs your going to create a global variable didResume. Inside the Appication_Activated event your going to set didResume to true. Now whenever your loading a page that would require user authentication check the variable to see if the user resumed and if they did you can handle it however you like. Here's the code for the app.xaml.cs:

```
  public static  bool didResume = false;
  private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        didResume = true;
    }
```

Now you just add this method to any page you want to protect:

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if(App.didResume)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

I think this should work since it really doesn't call any API that might not work on windows phone 7. Its simple and secure and will provide a solid user experience. Plus since it validates whenever the page is navigated to I think it will be harder for the user to attempt to bypass some how.

Answer (score -1):

In Application_Deactivated event just throw an exception

```
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("System Exit");
}
```

Comment: Throwing an exception to exit is a bad idea and not recommended by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn148258.aspx